# OAuth2 Authentication Webservice call BackEnd Client

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

Scenario: Have an application A that makes webservice calls to service on the other application. Everything is backend no UI. We are trying to do OAuth2/OpenId Authentication for this B2B communication. I am looking for some client which can take care of it without providing any UI. Can someone provide the details about which library or some sample code which can do this job without UI involved. I looked at spring Oauth2 client but that also need some level of UI.
Help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it SOAP based web service or REST based web service all? Does authentication server supports Client Credentials grant type?

Comment: Spring Security allows you to use the "client credentials" flow, which doesn't require any kind of UI. This section of the documentation may help you with getting started https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-the-access-token

Comment: It is SOAP Webservice. We have IDP server as Azure AD. Passing Username/password for authentication.

Comment: Eleftheria Stein-Kousathana: Could you please point me to the samples..? I was looking @ https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot.git

Comment: Caller --> Client --> Aws ALB --> Receiver

Comment: Flow (Caller --> Client --> Aws ALB --> Receiver)  Client receives username/password along with the actual request. Client should communicate with ALB and Other Idp server and sends the actual request to the receiver. I looked in to https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java they have webapp application sample that works fine for me if it is webapplication but here i do not have a way to provide credentails through web app.